# Convert sympy ordered pairs to list.

Tags: python, sympy

I have a list of ordered pairs from a SymPy Solver, `[(a,b),(c,d), etc.]` 
I need these values to be converted to a list to plug into another function like:

```
def func1(a, b):
     do_stuff
     print_stuff
```

I tried using `list(zip(*foo))` however it returned

```
[(-1.21566973175616,), (2.39458716469521,)]
```

which is useless. Any help would be appreciated, new to python (comp. physics class).

Comment: itertools did the trick! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're just looking for [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
>>> l = [(4, 3), (2, 6), (10, 2)]
>>> list(chain(*l))
[4, 3, 2, 6, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

im not 100% sure what you are asking but I hope this will help

```
lst = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

def func1(a,b):
    stuff = a+b # random 'do_stuff'
    print(stuff)

for x in lst:
    func1(*x) 
# the * will unpack x so that it will be accepted into the foo function, you could also do func1(x[0],x[1])
```